# Is this a possible exploit?

Tags: exploit, xss

For this application I am able to send a post request with the message `\n` and have it create new lines. The browser version chat message shows `` (4 new lines but they're boxes) when sending a chat message to other people.

Is it possible to exploit this behaviour in some way?

Comment: To be clear, sending "\n" changes how things appear for other users, correct?

Comment: Yes, it creates a new line. So instead of them seeing the \n they see a whole new line. @Tophandour

Comment: Also this isn't on a browser. this is on a application.

Comment: What do other escape sequences do? Try `\b`, `\0`, `\x3c`, etc. Also, does a `\\` at the end of a message break things?

Comment: /b Is just blank along with \0. \x3c outputs '<' and 'test\'' outputs test' @Arminius

Comment: So could this be an XSS flaw? What about `\x3csvg onload=alert(1)\x3e`?

Comment: Nope :/ the \n only works on the application it's self if you on the browser looking at the chat they'd just be boxes instead of new lines @Arminius

Comment: @leak by "box" do you mean the "□" character?

Comment: @Tophandour yes

Comment: Probably just unrecognized/can't be displayed by the receiver hence the box.

Comment: Your question is really "if the `\n` is parsed as a newline, could any code be injected?" and there is no way to tell from just this one simple experiment.

Comment: There could be format string vulnerability. If %d is replaced with a number, then it's likely that %n will trigger a write to the stack. Assuming ASLR and/or DEP are in use, this could be a vulnerability that's terrifically hard to exploit blindly (without access to the executable the server is using) though.

Comment: @AgentME %d is indeed replaced with a number when I do 'text':'%n' % 2, (in python) what is %n?